# SharePoint Online-Communication Site-Top Nav-How to target audience?

Tags: sharepoint-online, audience-targeting, communication-site, top-navigation

I am trying to setup audience targeting  for the top nav such that only the Site Owners  would be able to view a specific link.

I am not sure how to go about this?

I have tried looking at Managed Navigation but read somewhere that it may not be possible to target an audience.

I have also tried setting up an audience in the User Profile Section on the SharePoint Online Admin Center but not sure how to target a top nav for a site collection.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Sharepoint 2013 Audiences are managed on the Sharepoint server - do you have access to this?  An audience needs to be configured and users added to it.  I don't know if SP Online is different.

**Please note that using Audiences does not = security!**  You should configure access to the link you wish to keep secure by using the normal methods of Sharepoint groups.

OK, so that's the disclaimer out the way.  Here are some screen shots to show how it looks for me.  I have a site collection which is only visible for senior management.  Go in Site Settings>Navigation.  Here's how mine looks:

[image: nav1]

Select the heading (it is displayed as a folder):
[image: nav2]

Edit the folder:
[image]

Select the audience that should be allowed to see this link:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/20101822-enable-audience-targeting-on-modern-page-web-parts), audience targeting is being worked on for the "News web part, followed by the highlighted content and events web parts". In the comments, others have asked for audience targeting to be made available to the nav, but I'm not aware of a response to that request. If you need a link to show up for some users, you may need a custom spfx web part or extension.

The [SharePoint Starter Kit](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit) has code samples of headers and footers with dynamic links. Not quite what you're looking for, but perhaps it's a step in the right direction.